# Difference between pointer declaration and indirection

Tags: c++, c, pointers

I'm reading a book and I have doubts about what each of these syntax does. The first three lines I can understand but the following do not. Thank you very much if you help me, Julieta

```
int m; //m is int variable 
int *p; //Pointer p pointing to an integer value
p=&m //The memory address of the variable m is assigned to p

float *longitud;
longitud=&cable1;
*longitud=40.5;
```

Comment: `longitud=&cable1;` doesn't make much sense without knowing what `cable1` is.

Comment: Its basically the same what happens in the first 3 lines. The pointer longitud gets assigned with the adress of cable1, whatever cable1 might be. After that, you dereference the pointer to assign a value to cable1.

Comment: For strict type agreement use `*longitud = 40.5f ;` - the unadorned `40.5` is a `double` not a `float`.  Your compiler may otherwise issue warnings.

Comment: Don't edit your entire question away when it's solved. If someone answered your question you should accept their answer.

Answer (score 2):

The concepts of **value**, **pointer**, and **reference** often trip people up, especially as they are often taught to look at them in terms of *implementation* and not in terms of the language.

A **value** is a thing that exists and has meaning. It always has a *type* (a constraint on its meaning) like `int`, `float`, `char`, and `vector<string>`.

An **object** is a *value that exists somewhere in memory*. (And not, say, mangled into a machine instruction code or produced on-the-fly in some way. That is, I could take out my memory chip and stick my finger on it, were my fingers nimble enough.)

A **reference** is an *alias* — a name for an object. The name is convenient for us as programmers. How the compiler maintains that name does not really matter. All that matters (language perspective!) is that if you have a name, you have *direct access* to an object.

To put that into perspective, whenever you *name* an object, you obtain a *direct reference* to that object. You can manipulate that object directly using its name.

A **pointer** is a value. Its type is a location in the computer’s memory of some object. With this location, I can gain access to the object’s value. In other words, I can use a pointer to gain a direct reference to an object.

Vocabulary + time = fickle understandings and encourage people to ask useless things<sup>2</sup>. Let’s clean our minds up a little.

- First, a pointer is *not* a reference, it is an *indirect* reference. In order to get an actual, or *direct*, reference to a pointed-to object, we “*dereference*” the pointer. In other words, we perform a magic that transforms a pointer value to obtain a reference to an object.

The mechanics of how a pointer works are typically framed in terms of how the underlying hardware does something like “follows a pointer to a value”. We draw pictures with arrows and everything. We seem to forget to ask how this magic works. No one asks how variable names work either, but it is the exact same kind of magic. We simply trust when told “the compiler takes care of it”.

- What is missed is the distinction between a (direct) reference (an alias or name for an object) and an indirect reference (a pointer or other thing that can be used to obtain a reference to an object).

Before C++ the difference between direct and indirect references really only made sense in the context of a pointer, and it was easy to call a pointer “a reference” instead of the full phrase “an indirect reference”, and so the vocabulary words mixed around in our heads, and we began to misunderstand the actual concepts involved.

Enter C++, stage left. We now have things called “references” in addition to pointers. In terms of the language, they are true aliases for other objects<sup>1</sup>.

To put it to example:

```
int  x = 7;   // "x" is a reference to the integer object with value 7
int& y = x;   // "y" is a reference to the same integer object as "x".

int* p =      // "p" is a pointer object whose value is an 
              //     indirect reference to some integer object:
         &x;  // The & operator obtains an indirect reference (or pointer value) to "x"
```

And here is the last point. There are more than one meaning for "&"!

- When attached to a type, it means that the type is a direct reference to some object
- When attached to an object, it means that an indirect reference to that object is obtained

<sub><sup>1</sup> In C++, the abstraction leaks, because the lifetime of an object is bound only to the original reference. But that’s neither here nor there. There are other topics that deal with that here at SO.</sub>

<sub><sup>2</sup> So, to answer everyone’s favorite question: is a reference a pointer or not? The answer is, *it doesn’t matter*. (Unless you are writing a compiler.) You are asking implementation details about magic used to maintain a language-level concept. So sometimes it may be an actual pointer, sometimes it may simply be another entry in the compiler’s local symbol table, and it may even be something else if the compiler writer thinks it useful and appropriate.</sub>

<sub><sup>3</sup>Language gets to be fuzzy. I had previously said `"p" is a pointer`. Technically, it is an object whose value is a pointer type. We can usually get away by just saying what type of thing an object is, though, and be well-understood. It is only when we are splitting hairs (in context) that the vocabulary needs more care, as it does here.</sub>

Comment: Overall - quite good.  `int* p =     // "p" is a pointer  ... ` (`p` looks like an _object_ here.) and "A **pointer** is a value." could use some clarification.

Comment: @chux Thanks. Let me know if the fix needs more work.

Comment: Good luck on a potential [reversal](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/95/reversal)

Comment: Ah, thanks. I still don’t get all the tags and badges and hats and stuff.

Answer (score 1):

`longitude` is a pointer to a float variable

`longitud=&cable1` assigns the address of `cable1` (presumably a float?) to `longitud`, which now *references* `cable1`.

`*longitud=40.5` dereferences longitude and assign it value 40.5.  Because `longitud` references `cable1`, this assigns the value to `cable1`.  That is `*longitud` and `cable1` are the same thing.

None of this really relates to the question title *"Difference between pointer declaration and indirection"* - *indirection* is a general computing concept, and *pointers* are the means by which indirection is effected in C and C++.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you add one more (different) line in each section:

```
int m;              // m is int variable 
int *p;             // pointer p is pointing to an integer value
p = &m;             // the memory address of m is assigned to p
*p = 42;            // ADDED: assign 42 to m, where p points to

float cable1;       // ADDED: the variable where longitud points
float *longitud;    // pointer longitud is pointing to a float value
longitud = &cable1; // the memory address of cable1 is assigned to longitud
*longitud = 40.5f;  // assign 40.5 to cable1, where longitud points to
```

This completes the similar examples, which use different variable types.

Answer (score 1):

After executing the lines

```
float cable1;       // ADDED: the variable where longitud points
float *longitud;    // pointer longitud is pointing to a float value
longitud = &cable1; // the memory address of cable1 is assigned to longitud
```

the following conditions are true:

```
 longitude == &cable1
*longitude ==  cable1
```

IOW, the *expression* `*longitud` is equivalent to the expression `cable1`.  So when you write

```
*longitud = 40.5f;
```

this is equivalent to writing

```
cable1 = 40.5f;
```

The `*` operator *dereferences* the `longitud` pointer, such that the *expression* `*longitud` evaluates to the same thing as `cable1`.

Answer (score 0):

Cable1 needs to have a place memory before longitud can point to it.

The first 3 lines do this:

1. Set aside memory for an int.
2. Create an int pointer.
3. Get the int pointer to point at the int's memory address. Pointer references int.

The second 3 lines do this:

1. Create a float pointer.
2. Get the float pointer to point to a nonexistent address.
3. Try to assign a float value to that address.

If on line 4 you wrote:

```
float cable1;
```

You would have set aside memory and everything would work fine.

On the topic, you mean pointer declaration and dereferencing. I can give a short set of examples, though it mostly takes reading and practice to learn. Try these out and get a feel.

```
float f = 22.2f;   //sets aside memory for a float with the name "f", stores 22.2
float *pf;         //declares a float pointer.
pf = &f;           //sets pf to point to f's memory address. pf references p.
printf("%f", *pf); //prints the value at the referenced address (22.2)
printf("%x", pf);  //prints the memory address of the pointer itself
*pf = 33.3f;       //changes the value at f's address to 33.3 (from 22.2)
f = 44.4f;         //changes the value at f's address to 44.4 (from 33.3)
float *pf2;
*pf2 = 33.3        //BAD. pf2 is not assigned to an address, no value to change.
*pf2 = f;          //BAD. pf2 has no memory address to copy the value to.
*pf2 = pf;         //BAD. several reasons.
pf2 = pf;          //pf2 now points to f's address, too.
pf2 = &f;          //redundant. Same as the last line.
*pf2 = 55.5        //f has changed to 55.5. both pf2 and pf point to it.
```

Just think of the * as standing for "pointer" when you declare. When you use * later, it means "dereference." Dereferencing a pointer means you want to look at/use/change the referenced value. Later on, you'll learn that pointers can point to other pointers. So the value of a (char **) type is type (char *), rather than type (char).

If you don't have a book, I recommend C Programming - A Modern Approach 2nd Edition. It's a little dated but an excellent way to learn the fundamentals.